# how can use optional url in angular route with ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to define some state with optional url in angular ui-router

how can I do this?

for example

```
state('test',{
   url:'/list/:id/color?/:color?'
}
```

in this example the color and :color is optional and state should work whit these urls:

> site.com/list/1
>
> site.com/list/color/red

Comment: you can see here for more infomation . hope it help https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Answer (score 1):

There was an [**update**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108#issuecomment-40558474) to the library a few years ago which allowed this functionality:

```
$stateProvider.state("foo", {
  url: "/foo/{foo}",
  params: {
    foo: { value: "bar" }
  }
});
```

> Adding a default value to foo means that the route above will match
>   `/foo`, `/foo/`, and `/foo/baz`. Additionally, when matching `/foo` or `/foo/`,
>   `$stateParams` will still be populated with `{ foo: "bar" }`